# Remove Duplicate record from Mysql Table using Group By

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure and data below. 
[image]

I need to remove duplicate record from the table list. My confusion is that when I am firing query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY CONCAT(`name`,department)
```

then giving me correct list(12 records).

[image]

Same query when I am using the subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM `table` GROUP BY CONCAT(`name`,department))
```

It returning all record which is wrong.

[image: Table Structure]

So, My question is why `group by` in subquery is not woking.

Comment: it will provide same results, please check again, if still getting different results then create a #sqlfiddle so that can check the issue...further there is no need to use concat function as you can simply use group by name,department..

Comment: Actually name and department is combine primary key, Please use the link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fed956/2

Comment: I think your solution is not correct. You simply want to remove duplicate records or is it a must to use group by in your query? What i meant is if a give a solution without using group by, is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually as Tim mentioned in his answer that it to get first unique record by group by clause is not a standard feature of sql but mysql allows it till mysql5.6.16 version but from 5.6.21 it has been changed.

Just change mysql version in your sql fiddle and check that you will get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In the query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` GROUP BY CONCAT(`name`,department)
```

You are selecting the `id` column, which is a non-aggregate column.  Many RDBMS would give you an error, but MySQL allows this for performance reasons.  This means MySQL has to choose *which* record to retain in the result set.  Based on the result set in your original problem, it appears that MySQL is retaining the `id` of the first duplicate record, in cases where a group has more than one member.

In the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id FROM `table` GROUP BY CONCAT(`name`,department)
)
```

you are also selecting a non-aggregate column in the subquery.  It appears that MySQL actually decides which `id` value to be retained in the subquery based on the `id` value in the outer query.  That is, for each `id` value in `table`, MySQL performs the subquery and then selectively chooses to retain a record in the group if two `id` values match.

You should avoid using a non-aggregate column in a query with `GROUP BY`, because it is a violation of the ANSI standard, and as you have seen here it can result in unexpected results.  If you give us more information about what result set you want, we can give you a correct query which will avoid this problem.

I welcome anyone who has documentation to support these observations to either edit my question or post a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the *grouped ids* with that of table ids, so that you can get desired results.

**Example**:

```
SELECT t.* FROM so_q32175332 t
  JOIN ( SELECT id FROM so_q32175332
          GROUP BY CONCAT( name, department ) ) f
    ON t.id = f.id
 ORDER BY CONCAT( name, department );
```

Here `order by` was added just to compare directly the `*` results on `group`.

[image]

**Demo on SQL Fiddle**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d715a/1